# while invoking 'gnome-terminal' from the terminal , the environment variables of the previous session has a scope in the newly opened terminal

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal, environment-variables, bashrc

I have opened a gnome-terminal and did this:

```
$ export abc=abcd
$ echo $abc 
abcd
$ gnome-terminal
```

The above commands invoked an another gnome-terminal and tried this:

```
$ echo $abc
abcd   #I am not expecting this
```

My question is how to invoke 'gnome-terminal' with default environment variables(same as starting with ctrl+T)

Answer (score 1):

```
gnome-terminal --no-environment
```

Comment: # Failed to parse arguments: Unknown option --no-environment

Comment: `gnome-terminal -h` shows the various options, isn't there an argument that says "Do not pass the environment"

Comment: There is no argument like that. I checked with 'man' and gnome-terminal --help-all

Comment: GNOME Terminal 3.42 has this option in [source code](https://codesearch.debian.net/search?q=no-environment+package%3A%5CQgnome-terminal%5CE&literal=1), so we need to know version of gnome-terminal used by OP (@saigokul) .

Comment: GNOME Terminal 3.36.2 on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: Then this feature you want is present in latest gnome-terminal. Update your version to get it :)